# How can I edit a PHP command using PHP?

Tags: php, edit

So, I'm a PHP newbie who has been trying to do a PHP program that will edit some other PHP program by adding some more info.

How I want this to work:

1. You send PHP request to `edit.php` with an argument `add=(text)`, (text) is some random text you may want to add.
2. `(text)` gets added to `raw.php` by changing 2nd line from `echo "(already existing text)"` to `echo "(already existing text) (text)"`

Can somebody help me? I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why you need to do this? why not using variables?

Comment: This is not a good pratice

Comment: I too want to warn you that whatever you're trying to do isn't what you'd call good practice @stysan!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @islemdev like `$text = "(already existing text) (text)"` instead of `echo "(already existing text) (text)"`?

Comment: i mean, instead of changing the script, keep in script echo "(already existing text) $text"; then pass this $text from get params or from function params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you this aternative way:
Add a new file for the text content, a JSON file would be perfect, but i don't want to make it more complicated, we will stick with a txt for now.
It's not good to edit the php source code with another php script, it is often done by malicious script.

So we have:

1. edit.php (this will fire the GET request)
2. raw.php (it will do the thing)
3. mycontent.txt (it will store the text content)

```
//This is raw.php

/*This is the new content retrived with GET*/
$my_new_content = $_GET["add"]; 

/*Update txt file with the new content, 
the new text will be append, I add an extra space in the front.*/
file_put_contents("mycontent.txt", " " . $my_new_content, FILE_APPEND); 

/* Read the actual text from the txt file */
$my_brand_new_content = file_get_contents("mycontent.txt"); 

echo $my_brand_new_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to access "raw.php" content using "file_get_contents" function check this link

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

- You need to add special string in the target place in "raw.php" like "*TARGET_PLACE_TEXT*" ... THEN use "str_replace" function check this link

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

- To save the new file content check this link

[file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

IF you can send Your code, I'll make a function to do this job for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add text, than use mysql. From edit.php store the input text to mysql table. Then in raw.php just query the table in asc order to see text appear in the same way

```
(already existing text) 
(text)
```

and so on

Comment: Are you should you need a **mysql** table for this?

Comment: If its about adding text, it's easier and better approach. No need to write complex code for simple tasks

Comment: So, you want to use a complex tool (MySQL can do really complex stuff) to do a simple task like replacing some text with another text?  I tin [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) or [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is more than enough, and that is already available in PHP